# Kotlin get ids of selected options

Tags: android, kotlin

I have multiple option select and I need to get array of selected options but all I get is latest option selected.

`Code`

```
class PublishActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
    var selectedTags: List<String>? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_publish)

        pTags.setOnClickListener {
            var tagIds = ArrayList<String>()
            val tagOptions = ArrayList<String>()
            for (i in tags) {
                tagOptions.add(i.title)
                tagIds.add(i.id)
            }
            var checkedItems = ArrayList<Int>()
            checkedItems.forEach{ index -> tagIds[index + 1] }

            MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this)
                .setTitle(resources.getString(R.string.project_tags))
                .setMultiChoiceItems(tagOptions.toTypedArray(), null) { dialog, which, checked ->
                    if (checked) {
                        checkedItems.add(which)
                    } else if (checkedItems.contains(which)) {
                        checkedItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(which))
                    }
                    // Respond to item chosen
                    pTags.setText("${checkedItems.size} tags selected")
                }
                .setPositiveButton(resources.getString(R.string.ok)) { dialog, which ->
                    for (i in checkedItems) {
                        Log.d("eeee1", tagOptions[i])
                        selectedTags = listOf(tagOptions[i])
                    }
                }
                .setNeutralButton(resources.getString(R.string.clear)) { dialog, which ->
                    pTags.text = null
                    pTags.hint = "0 tag selected"
                    if (checkedItems.size > 0) {
                        checkedItems.clear()
                    }
                }
                .show()
        }
    }
}
```

`Log.d("eeee1", tagOptions[i])` returns such data in logcat

```
D/eeee1: 3D Printing
D/eeee1: 3D Architecture
D/eeee1: .NET/Mono
D/eeee1: ActionScript
```

but in my `selectedTags` I get only `D/eeer1: [ActionScript]`

It supposed to give me something like this `D/eeer1: ["3D Printing", "3D Architecture", ".NET/Mono", "ActionScript"]`

> **PS:** what I'm actually look to achieve here is to get `id` of those `selected items` instead of their names that's why I have `var tagIds = ArrayList<String>()` but if that's not possible to achieve as long as it just return array of all names (like sample above) it's fine by me as well.

**Any idea?**

Comment: Use something like: `val checkedItems = booleanArrayOf(false, false, false, false)` and in the `.setMultiChoiceItems` just set: `checkedItems[which] = checked}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code sets your variable to a list with a single item. So you just overwrite your variable over and over again

```
selectedTags = listOf(tagOptions[i])
```

you need:

```
//Declaration
var selectedTags: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()

...
// In loop
selectedTags.add(tagOptions[i])
```

You could also do it with a more functional approach:

```
//Declaration
var selectedTags: List<String>? = listOf()

...
// Skip the loop and use the map function
.setPositiveButton(resources.getString(R.string.ok)) { dialog, which ->
    selectedTags = checkedItems.map{ tagOptions[it] }
}
```

To get the Id's instead of the titles you should just be able to use your tagIds instead of tagOptions. Just make sure that you get your typing right. The `selectedTags` list needs to be of the same type as tag.id.

Comment: I am getting `Function invocation 'listOf(...)' expected`

Comment: Ah sorry, fixed it, it should've been selectedTags there

Comment: now the `add` is red and it says `Unresolved reference: add`

Comment: add is correct, it is a method on mutableList, did you change selectedTags to a mutable list? (you can not add things to a list in kotlin since it is immutable)

Comment: yes I used your code `var selectedTags: List<String> = mutableListOf()` but `add` is still red

Comment: Ahh I see, fixed it. You need the variable to be declared as a mutable list. I fixed it in the answer. Now it should work

Comment: in `.map(tagOptions[i])` it says `Type mismatch.
Required:
(TypeVariable(T)) → TypeVariable(R)
Found:
String`

Comment: Also I think your `[i]` part doesn't exist anymore as you removed the loop (not sure)

Comment: You're correct, it should be the kotlin keyword 'it'

Comment: still getting `Required:
(TypeVariable(T)) → TypeVariable(R)
Found:
String`

Comment: I used the wrong brackets, damn i really botched this answer! Sorry about that :)

Comment: Thank you it does get all my selected items however they are not presented as strings like `["a", "b"]` they are returning like `[a, b]` (it's not a problem i can manage fixing that in backend, but do you have idea about my question `ps` part? (getting ids instead of names?)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting only last inserted value because you are creating fresh list when `ok` button is clicked and assigning it to `selectedTags`. Problem at `selectedTags = listOf(tagOptions[i])` line of your code.

Solution:

Declare a single list and put selected values into it. Like :

```
val selectedTags = arrayListOf<String>()
```

then use below code inside `ok` button click:

```
              .setPositiveButton("Ok") { dialog, which ->
              for (i in checkedItems) {
                //selectedTags = listOf(tagOptions[i])
                selectedTags.add(tagOptions[i])
              }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you this part has been solved by help of `Adam` what I'm looking to achieve now is my `PS:` part of my question. Any idea on that?